# Shuffle an array of Q&A pairs

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, shuffle

What is the best way you think to shuffle a  multi-dimensional array in the following structure, so that question-answer pairs are ***separated***?

```
$myArray = array(

  array('question' => 'q1', 'answer' => 'a1'),
  array('question' => 'q2', 'answer' => 'a2'),
  array('question' => 'q3', 'answer' => 'a3')
  //...
  //...

);
```

What I need is to turn this:

```
q1-a1, q2-a2, q3-a3...
```

into this:

```
q3-a2, q4-a3, q1-a9...
```

*I get this array from a questions database. I want to display question-answer pairs but shuffled obviously. I have a few solutions in my mind, just curious for clever ways to do it ;)*

Comment: shuffle it during select?

Comment: No, because I would need the correct question-answer pairs too in order to check against when needed.

Comment: then use `shuffle()`? seems straightforward

Comment: shuffle() shuffles the order of the elements in the array, I want to shuffle both the order and the pairs. Something like: q1-a2, q3-a4, q5-a1...

Comment: @Serdar Check the solution below, I think it will do what you are wanting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could just simply get the questions and answers, shuffle them, then reapply:

```
$q = $a = array();
foreach ($myArray as $value) {
    $q[] = $value['question'];
    $a[] = $value['answer'];
}

shuffle($q);
shuffle($a);

foreach($myArray as $key => &$value) {
    $value['question'] = $q[$key];
    $value['answer'] = $a[$key];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($myArray);
```

You could also use `array_collumn()` if available (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0):

```
$q = array_column($myArray, 'question');
$a = array_column($myArray, 'answer');
```

Comment: This is close to what I actually did.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a plethora amount of built-in [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php). Using a combination of these functions, you could create a custom shuffle function that uses `array_keys`, `array_values`, `shuffle` and `array_combine` internally. Try the following:

```
// Create a copy of the original array to key
// for processing later...
$originalArray = $myArray;

function shuffleAll($myArray) {
   // Pull the keys into an array and
   // pull the values into another
   // array...
   $keys = array_keys($myArray);
   $values = array_values($myArray);

   // Shuffle the arrays independently...
   shuffle($keys);
   shuffle($values);        

    // Combine the arrays into one... 
    return array_combine($keys, $values);
}

$myArray = shuffleAll($myArray);
```

`$myArray` should now have a custom assortment of your now non-matching key-value pairs. The original values have been preserved in `$originalArray` for latter processing and matching.

**References:**

[`array_combine(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)
[`array_keys(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)
[`array_values(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)
[`shuffle(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

Comment: You call your function `shuffleAll` without the `$myArray` parameter. It also does not give the intended output.

Comment: @KeVin Thanks for the catch on the parameter. How does it not give the desired output? According to the OP, _"I want to shuffle both the order and the pairs. Something like: q1-a2, q3-a4, q5-a1... "_ This was an example not a requirement. Where do you see an _"intended output"_...

Comment: He wants to mix questions and answers: `q1-a2, q3-a4, q5-a1`. Your function does the same as `shuffle($myArray)`.

Comment: @KeVin You did not read through the answer fully. The `keys` are extracted and shuffled, the `values` are extracted and shuffled. The two are then placed back into an array where the `keys` are still the `keys` and the `values` are still the `values`. They're just shuffled. According to the shuffle docs: _"This function assigns new keys to the elements in array. It will remove any existing keys that may have been assigned, rather than just reordering the keys."_ By breaking out the two arrays and recombining them, I'm ensuring that the OP does not end up with a new set of keys.

Comment: @KeVin You could get the mix described above in your comment, but you may not. That I will acknowledge for sure. It seemed like a suggestion though rather than a requirement. If the OP can provide some feedback on the desired output, I'll be happy to modify the answer if it is wrong...